# How to use an array inside a GraphQL Query Variable

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

I'd like to use an array inside a GraphQL query variable so that I can get the data of more than one product from a single query with Gatsby however at the moment I get errors.

My graphQL query looks like:

```
query ($id: [String!]) {
  shopifyProduct(handle: {eq: $id}) {
    handle
    id
    title
    handle
    productType
    shopifyId
  }
}
```

and my Query Variable looks like:

```
{
  "id": ["liner-jacket", "pocket-t-shirt"]
}
```

The desired response would be (something like):

```
{
  "data": {
    "shopifyProduct": {
      "handle": "liner-jacket",
      "id": "Shopify__Product__hopbjidjoqjndadnawdawda123123=",
      "title": "Liner Jacket",
      "productType": "jacket",
      "shopifyId": "hopbjidjoqjndadnawdawda123123="
    },
    "shopifyProduct": {
      "handle": "pocket-t-shirt",
      "id": "Shopify__Product__iajwdoiajdoadjwaowda4023123=",
      "title": "Pocket T-Shirt",
      "productType": "t-shirt",
      "shopifyId": "iajwdoiajdoadjwaowda4023123="
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GraphQL supports a special List type that represents an array of a particular type. For example, `[String]` is a List of the type `String`. Even though the `[String]` type *wraps* `String`, in GraphQL it is considered a *separate*, *distinct* type from `String`. In other words, you can't use `[String]` where `String` is expected and you can't use `String` where `[String]` is expected.

An argument (like `handle`) or input object field (like `eq`) only has a single GraphQL type. If a variable is used as the value of an argument, its type must match that argument's type. It appears `eq` has the type `String!` (a non-null String), so you can only pass it a single `String`, not a List.

Whether a way exists to query based on an array of values is up to the server implementation. Some schemas support a way to do that (for example, instead of `eq`, there may be an `in` field that accepts a List). However, this is schema-specific. Review the document for the server/framework/library you're using, or explore the schema using an available GraphiQL or GraphQL Playground interface.